# cron job to update a file from ftp

Tags: ftp, cron, wget

I tried something like:
wget ftp://username:password@ftp.somedomain.com/bla/blabla.txt -x /home/weptile/public_html/bla/blabla.txt

Appereantly -x writes the output :) I thought it was overwriting the file I need.

So what I'm trying to do is do daily updates on blabla.txt in this specific subdirectory from an external ftp file. I want to get the file from ftp and overwrite the old file on my server.

Comment: Try to get help using: `man wget`

Answer (score 1):

Use `wget -N` to overwrite existing files.

---

If you get stuck on stuff like this, try `man wget` or heck, even [Google](http://google.com/).

Comment: I have no idea about cron jobs or unix commands. And I posted the question here after digging google and trying to understand what to do for 2 days (well, total of few hours)... So I thought, since the cron documentations and manuals all around are not clear enough to help a newbie like me, I asked here. I want to get file and save to a specific location. I can get the file and save to the root, but not to the directory. And if I get the file, it doesn't overwrite.